How to show measurability of a certain map involving a product sigma algebra?
I am having trouble to show that a certain map is measurable. I asked a similar question a while ago (see here). I simplified the problem in hope to get a reply.
Define $W = C([0,\infty), \mathbb{R})$ and define for each $t \geq 0$ the sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}_t = \sigma(\pi_s:s\in [0,t])$, where $\pi_s: W \to \mathbb{R}; w \mapsto w_s$. Hence, $\mathcal{G}_t$ is the smallest sigma algebra such that all maps $\pi_s$, $s\leq t$, are measurable.
Problem: I am trying to show that the map $\pi: [0,t] \times W \to \mathbb{R}; (s,w) \mapsto w_s$ is $\mathcal{B}_{[0,t]} \otimes \mathcal{G}_t$-measurable.
It does not seem as easy as I thought. I know that the maps $w \mapsto w_s$ is $\mathcal{G}_t$-measurable for each $s \leq t$ and $s \mapsto w_s$ is $\mathcal{B}_{[0,t]}$-measurable by continuity of each $w \in W$. But I cannot seem to figure out how to translate this to the measurability when both variables vary.
I would be glad for any hint or suggestion on how to tackle this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Here is a fairly standard argument: Let $X_n(s,w)=\sum_i w_{i/n}1_{\frac  {i-1} n \le s <\frac   i n}$. Use continuity to see that $X_n(s,w)\to w_s$ pointwise. It is clear that each term in the sum is $\mathcal{B}_{[0,t]} \otimes \mathcal{G}_t$measurable.

Great, thanks! Nice and quick answer.
